# Drupal Block Configuration

Tags: drupal

I'm not familiar with the back end of drupal whatsoever. All I'm using is the web interface. I've been trying to modify a block in order for it to be on one page only.

I read this:
Specify pages by using their paths. Enter one path per line. The '*' character is a wildcard. Example paths are blog for the blog page and blog/* for every personal blog.  is the front page. If the PHP option is chosen, enter PHP code between . Note that executing incorrect PHP code can break your Drupal site.

But when I try to do the same with one of my pages it just doesn't work. The only one that does is front. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you specify the path that you're using?  Does it begin with a preceding slash (eg. `/node/1`)?  If so, you want to remove the preceding slash.

Comment: I don't know...For example I have a page that looks like this mywebsite/?q=node/13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try node/13

And make sure it is set to "Only on the listed pages"

The value of q is what you want to use for the path in the case where you are not using path aliases.